# Make compatible custom menu widget for Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: menus, widgets, navigation, twitter-bootstrap

If I configure `wp_nav_menu` function, I can put the "items_wrap" option to achieve a nice navigation given by Twitter Bootstrap, thus: `<ul class="nav nav-pills">%3$s</ul>`. But, how to configure the custom menu widget to do the same? I mean, for achieve `<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">%3$s</ul>` in all custom menu widgets, by default.

Thanks for help!
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter `'wp_nav_menu_args'`.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'wpse_79901_nav_menu' );

function wpse_79901_nav_menu( $args )
{
    $args['items_wrap'] = '<ul class="nav nav-pills">%3$s</ul>';
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Great! But that would affect all existing item_wrap of each wp_menu_nav() defined and I just want to change item_wrap to custom menu widget ... I decided to make the following, tell me if it's the best way to do it: `if(!$args['fallback_cb']){ $args['items_wrap'] = '<ul class="nav nav-pills">%3$s</ul>'; } return $args;`. Works for me, but I don't know if it's the best way to do it.

Comment: @markotom That’s exactly how it should be done. :)